# Modify an AccuRev transaction comment

Tags: accurev

In AccuRev, is there a way to change the comment I provided for a transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't change a comment that's already been submitted, that would violate AccuRev's Timesafe Architecture.  In the future, we will potentially be adding the capability to "amend" the comment while retaining the previous history.  This isn't there yet, but does already have an existing enhancement request.  Hope this info helps you out...

Cheers,
~James